# ZeroMQ REQ/REP performance

Tags: c++, zeromq

Consider the following two processes:

sender.cpp:

```
#include <zhelpers.h>
...
zmq::context_t ctx(1);
...
void foo(int i)
{
   zmq::socket_t sender(ctx, ZMQ_REQ);
   sender.connect("tcp://hostname:5000");

   std::stringstream ss;
   ss <<"bar_" <<i;
   std::string bar_i(std::move(ss.str());

   s_sendmore(sender, "foo ");
   (i != N) ? s_send(sender, bar, 0) : s_send(sender, "done", 0);
   s_recv(sender);
}

int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i<=100000; ++i)
        foo(i);
    return 0;
}
```

receiver.cpp

```
#include <zhelpers.h>
...
int main()
{
    zmq::context_t ctx(1);
    zmq::socket_t rcv(ctx, ZMQ_REP);
    rcv.bind("tcp://*:5000");

    std::string s1("");
    std::string s2("");

    while(s2 != "done")
    {
        s1 = std::move(s_recv(rcv));
        s2 = std::move(s_recv(rcv));
        std::cout <<"received: " <<s1 <<" " <<s2 <<"\n";
        s_send(rcv, "ACK");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Let's start the two processes. What I'd expect is that the receiver process will receive all the messages that the sender sends to it and it'll print out:

```
foo bar_1
foo bar_2
...
```

and so on, till:

```
...
foo bar_100000
```

And I'd expect it will do this without any blocking.

My problem is that the receiver always sticks around the 28215th iteration (always around that number!!!) and blocks till a minute or so. Then it goes further till 100000, but sometimes it sticks again. My question is of course: why is this happening? How can I fix it?

I tried to put 'sender' within foo(.) in the global scope, and then it worked: in that case all the print-outs went from 1 to 100000 smoothly and super-fast, without any blocking (of course in that case the socket was not created each time foo(.) was called). But unfortunately in my code I cannot do that.

I'd like to understand why is this block happens.

Comment: the max sockets might be limited on the server side. Try to increase it might solve it. because it takes time for tcp to clean dead sockets and you have a lot of those you are hitting the maximum number of sockets.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your examples are not veryfiable, since they do not compile. So here are some exapmles that should be close to your intent and actually compile

sender.cpp

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void send(const std::string& msg)
{
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);

    std::cout << "Connecting to receiver ..." << std::endl;
    socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:5555");

    zmq::message_t request (100);
    memcpy (request.data (), msg.c_str(), 100);
    std::cout << "Sending message " << msg << "..." << std::endl;
    socket.send (request);
}

int main ()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        send(std::to_string(i));
    }
    send("done");
}
```

use something linke

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I/home/dev/cppzmq -I/home/dev/libzmq/include sender.cpp -lzmq -o sender
```

receiver.cpp

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    socket.bind ("tcp://*:5555");

    char buf[100] = {0};
    while (std::string(buf).compare("done")) {
        zmq::message_t request;

        //  Wait for next request from client
        socket.recv (&request);
        std::memcpy(buf, request.data(), 100);
        std::cout << "Received message " << buf << std::endl;

        //  Send reply back to client
        zmq::message_t reply (5);
        memcpy (reply.data (), "Hello", 5);
        socket.send (reply);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

use

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I/home/dev/cppzmq -I/home/dev/libzmq/include receiver.cpp -lzmq -o receiver
```

when starting the processes, everything seems to work fine, output on the receiver is as expected with no breaks:

```
Received message 99996
Received message 99997
Received message 99998
Received message 99999
Received message done
```

but what i expected: have a look at netstat:

```
netstat
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 localhost:38345         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:46228         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:60309         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:46916         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:47600         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:54454         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:46409         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:51142         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:40355         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:40005         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:45614         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:48974         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:41427         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:58740         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:58754         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:60044         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:57478         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:50419         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:44361         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:37284         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:38662         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:45968         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:57407         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:59200         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:41292         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:55243         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:51489         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:48865         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:35491         localhost:5555          TIME_WAIT 
...
```

I have over 20k (!) such sockets in TIME_WAIT state after one run. This is because of the variable scope of `socket` in `void send(...)` in `sender.cpp`. I don't know exactly what zmq does when destroying the socket when it's getting out of scope, but i'm pretty sure it will call `close()` on the socket's fd somewhere which will bring your socket in this TIME_WAIT state. Even if my sender and receiver run smooth, i don't know how your system handles this much sockets. Also, i don't know what your `zhelpers.h` file does. But I know that if you place your socket in a global scope, only one close() call will happen on the sender side on one single socket. I´d start here to investigate more. Maybe, have a look at [how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait](https://serverfault.com/questions/329845/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait) ...

Comment: Thanks. Will check. Sorry about my code didn't compile. I just meant to show you the problem itself (that is why I used the '...' for instance.). I did not want to go to every detail. The zhelpers.h can be found here for example: https://github.com/imatix/zguide2/tree/master/examples/C%2B%2B

Comment: One other thing is, maybe you just don't want to declare your sending socket variable in the global scope but you solve the issue with the thousands of TIME_WAIT stated socket's already if you just make the scope a little bit larger, i.e. declare it outside your sending loop and re-use it at least for sending the 100000 messages.